# How can I echo a Link to a wp page from a specific directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I am working with:

`echo '<a href="' . bloginfo('template_directory')  . $slug['slug'] . '">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>' .$markup;`

It currently links correctly but shows the entire http string before the link. 
Example: http://www.blah.com/blah/blahPortfolio. When it should be just "Portfolio".
Fresh eyes on this would be so helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be echoing `<?php` also?

Comment: Please do not edit the original question to just say you solved it. you can add your own answer, and explain how you solved it. This way, this post may help future visitors. I rolled your question back to its previous state.

Comment: It is not solved. I ended up working around it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors that I can see:

1. `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` If you are using `echo` it means `<?php` tag is already open so use only `bloginfo('template_directory')`
2. There are two closing tag for a tag (i.e. `/>`) You use only one (i.e. `>`)

So the code will be like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/thepage.php' . $slug['slug'] . '">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
```

Comment: remove "/" from  '/">' and make it ' "> ' if still not done please post the actual output

Comment: so you mean to say link should be **http://colorgazelle.com/framework/wp-content/themes/thetheme/thepage.php**   for this i have edited my post again

Comment: check the value of $post_type->labels->singular_name

Comment: @please provide URL Of the page where you are getting error? else I will not be clear what is actually happening.

Comment: ok I think you are wrong in doing echo the link  I m not wordpress expert but there must be a way to add link in breadcrumb sorry cant help with wordpress

Comment: hay man its you tag. your question only contains PHP  not  wordpress tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this code chunk and let me know --

```
echo '<a href="' . '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>'.'thepage.php />' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
```

Comment: @EmpFX  
Check your 'thepage.php /> and '/">' , i think your "/>" is not working correctly , let me know what link you are trying to create??